# Tangent vectors to a point with zero gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, examples-counterexamples, tangent-spaces

In the book Elementary Differential Geometry by Andrew Pressley the following theorem is proven:

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth. Let $p \in U$ be such that $\nabla f (p) \neq 0$ (he calls this a regular point), and let $c = f(p)$. Then the set of all vectors tangent to $f^{-1}[\{c\}]$ is equal to $[\nabla f (p)]^\perp:= \{v \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, v \cdot \nabla f (p) = 0 \}$.

A tangent vector to $f^{-1}[\{c\}]$ at $p$ is defined as a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v = \alpha'(0)$ for some smooth $\alpha : (-1, 1) \to U$ with $\alpha(t) \in f^{-1}[\{c\}]$ for all $t \in (-1,1)$.

This theorem implies that, for all regular points $p$, **the set of all tangent vectors to the level set $p$ is a vector space**. In particular it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. My question is **what can we say in the case that $p$ is not a regular point**.

In other words, supposing the situation is above except that $\nabla f(p) = 0$, is it true that $$\{\alpha'(0) \, | \, \alpha \in C^{\infty}((-1,1), U), \, \alpha(0) = p, \, \alpha(t) \in f^{-1}[\{c\}] \,  \forall t \in (-1,1) \}$$ is a vector space?

Comment: Have you tried the vertex of a cone?

Comment: @TedShifrin I think in that case there would be no smooth alpha passing though the vertex and so the set of tangent vectors would be empty. Indeed this is an example that answers the question, however do you know of an example where the set of tangent vectors is non-empty

Comment: No, double cone. Then lots of smooth curves.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh I see, would you like to write an answer so the question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the origin in the (double) cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$. Your set of tangent vectors to curves gives you the entire cone. This is certainly not a vector space, and it spans all of $\Bbb R^3$. Relevant things to look up are *tangent cone* and *Zariski tangent space*.